# Automatic Columns in React-Table not working with JSON Arrays

Tags: javascript, react-table

I'm trying to dynamically generate a table from a fetch request. It's able to do it with JSON data without an array name, however when it does, it doesn't work. Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/static-example-319q4

Here, the example works fine with the data that doesn't have an array name for the JSON data, however, when the other componentDidMount function is used, it doesn't work even though I specified the array name using "posts.launches".

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      value: '',
    }
  }


/*
Get response from an API endpoint and populates the 
*/
componentDidMount() {
    //const params = this.state.text
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({ posts: posts });
      });
  }

/*
  componentDidMount() {
    //const params = this.state.text
    const url = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({ posts: posts.hits });
      });
  }

*/


  getColumns() {
    const getPostKeys = this.state.posts[0];
    if (getPostKeys) {
      const column =
        this.state.posts &&
        Object.keys(getPostKeys).map(key => {
          return {
            Header: key,
            accessor: key
          };
        });
      return column;
    } else {
      console.log("Error")
      return [];
    }
  }

   render() {
     console.log(this.state.posts[0])
    const columns = this.getColumns();
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.initial_data));
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={this.state.posts}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
          filterable
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some of the data in your JSON is not consistent with the input that React Table expects its to be in a grid. Check for the condition in working example -

`"_tags" && x !== "_highlightResult"`

After removing these keys, I further baked the columns and its working fine. Please check the working example -

https://codesandbox.io/s/static-example-x2kjr

Code -

```
getColumns() {
          const getPostKeys = this.state.posts[0];
          if (getPostKeys) {
            function isNotTagsOrHighlightKey(x) {
              return x !== "_tags" && x !== "_highlightResult";
            }
            const getSanitizedColumns = Object.keys(getPostKeys).filter(
              isNotTagsOrHighlightKey
            );
            const newColumn = getSanitizedColumns.map(key => {
              return {
                Header: key,
                accessor: key
              };
            });
            return newColumn;
          } else {
            console.log("Error");
            return [];
          }
        }
```